# Return value from nested function 'not defined'

Tags: python, nested-function

I have a nested function that is returning two values. When I try to call those values I get an error saying its not defined.

```py
    async def wallet(self, interaction:discord.Interaction, button:discord.ui.Button):

        ### Blah blah blah ###
        
        @sync_to_async
        def get_user_wallet():

            private_key = abc
            wallet = xyz

            return wallet, private_key

        await get_user_wallet()
        view = secretKeyView(private_key) #private_key is not defined#
        await interaction.response.send_message()
```

I'm not quite sure what is off, I am pretty sure I am returning the values properly why is it saying it's not defined?

I appreciate any clarity you can give.
Thanks!

Comment: `wallet, private_key = await get_user_wallet()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that instead of abc and xyz you are using actual values.  If you are not then they would be your issue. You try to pass the variable **private_key** to the function `secretKeyView()`.  But you don't actually define **private_key** outside the scope of your `get_user_wallet()` function.  This function returns values so if you want to use them, you must assign the return value of this function to a variable(s).  See below:

```
wallet, private_key = await get_user_wallet()
view = secretKeyView(private_key) #private_key IS defined#
await interaction.response.send_message()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are returning the values but not storing them anywhere

```
wallet, private_key = await get_user_wallet()
```